# Haskell concat / filter according specific rules

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

According to following rules, I tried to solve the following problem:

1. No definition of recursion
2. No List of Comprehension
3. Only Prelude-Module is allowed.

Now I have to implement higher-order for **concat** and **filter**.

Im at this point:

```
concat' :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat' a = (concat a)

filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p [] = []
filter' p (x:xs) 
            | p x = x : filter p xs
            | otherwise = filter p xs
```

The concat function is working (nothing special so far) -> Is that a defined recursion? I mean I use the predefined concat from standard-prelude but myself I don't define it - or am I wrong?

For the filter, the function I've looked up the definition of standard prelude but that's either not working and it contains a definition of recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supposing the `concat` and `filter` functions should be avoided. Why would we need to implement `concat` and `filter` if they're already available? So try implementing them from scratch.

We can use [*folding*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold) instead of recursion and list comprehensions. The below solutions use the function `foldr`.

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

```
concat' :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat' = foldr (++) []

filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p = foldr (\x acc -> if p x then x:acc else acc) []
```

Examples:

```
main = do
  print $ concat' ["A", "B", "CAB"]    -- "ABCAB"
  print $ filter' (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 0) [1..9]  -- [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score -1):

You may do as follows;

```
concat' :: Monad m => m (m b) -> m b
concat' = (id =<<)

filter' p = ((\x-> if p x then [x] else []) =<<)
```

`=<<` is just flipped version of the monadic bind operator `>>=`.

```
filter' (< 10) [1,2,3,10,11,12]
[1,2,3]
```